# Adding grammar causes speech recognition to fail

Tags: python, speech-recognition, grammar, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am rather perplexed over how to use grammar files with Python's `speech_recognition` package. I've tried hunting for solutions online, but information is *sparse* to say the least regarding grammars. Here's my setup:

**main.py:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr

converter = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Please say "zero":')
    audio = converter.listen(source)

print('Without: ' + str(converter.recognize_sphinx(audio, show_all=False)))
print('With: ' + str(converter.recognize_sphinx(audio, show_all=False, grammar='Numbers.jsgf')))
```

**Numbers.jsgf:**

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar Numbers;
<Zero> = ( zero );
```

**Output:**

```
Please say "zero":
Without: zero
INFO: jsgf.c(706): Defined rule: <Numbers.g00000>
INFO: jsgf.c(706): Defined rule: <Numbers.Zero>

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I'm working in PyCharm, using `Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`. Any ideas what's going on? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much tinkering, and comparing against some of the examples from the [project page](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) I finally discovered what the bug was. It boils down to a naming convention that isn't easy to find if you don't know to look for it or what you're looking for. This is an incorrect file:

**Numbers.jsgf**

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar Values;
<Zero> = ( zero );
```

And this is a correct file:

**Numbers.jsgf**

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar Numbers;
<Numbers> = ( zero );
```

To explain it simply:

- The file name *MUST* be the same as the grammar name
- There *MUST* be one grammar rule (e.g. `<Numbers>`) with the same name as the file / grammar name

If either of those conditions isn't met, then the program won't be able to understand the file and will crash. As a side note, `.jsgf` and `.gram` files are referencing the same coding standards, and the extension seems to come down to personal taste.